# Office365 File.UploadAsync does not work on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, office365api

I am trying to upload a file from a **Windows 10 UWP** application to an Office 365 OneDrive, using the code below:

```
Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.FileServices.File newFile = 
                        new Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.FileServices.File
    {
        Name = fileName
    };

await sharePointClient.Files.GetById(parentId).ToFolder().Children.AddItemAsync(newFile);
await sharePointClient.Files.GetById(newFile.Id).ToFile().UploadAsync(stream);
```

The File is created on OneDrive, but the content is not uploaded.
Please note that the exact same code works from a Windows 8 Store application.

Looking at differences between Windows 8 and Windows 10 application behaviors, I noticed, in Fiddler, that the file upload REST service is not called from the Win10 application SDK.

Please advise, if anyone has encountered similar SDK failures when running an app under Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can, but try to use the decompiler and debug the Microsoft code and see what is going wrong. Mabye you can actualy "fix it" with some reflection.